# How do I get a single read action using Contains in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was trying to replace this code

```
var sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM AgreementTexts WHERE IsSelected = 1 AND HeadLineID IN ({0}) ORDER BY consNumber", headLineIDs);

var exampelTexts = await _db.Database.SqlQuery<AgreementExampelTextViewModel>(sql).ToListAsync();
```

with the following LINQ statements:

```
var query = _db.AgreementTexts
               .Where(aet => aet.IsSelected && listOfHeadLineIDs.Contains(aet.HeadLineID))
               .OrderBy(aet => aet.consNumber);

var exampelTexts = (await query.ToListAsync()).ToAgreementExampelTextViewModel();
```

However there was a big performance drop. Logging the calls the first example generates a single request to the database while the other example results in requests closing and opening the connection in between.

Is there a way for making the second example perform a single request?

Comment: What Version of EF?  And what is `ToAgreementExampelTextViewModel` doing?  Perhaps Lazy Loading?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Distinct method to optimize your query as below :

```
var query = _db.AgreementTexts
                   .Where(aet => aet.IsSelected && listOfHeadLineIDs.Distinct().Contains(aet.HeadLineID))
                   .OrderBy(aet => aet.consNumber);

var exampelTexts = (await query.ToListAsync()).ToAgreementExampelTextViewModel();
```